# Are holders of a temporary residence permit from an EU country eligible for free admission to the Louvre?

Tags: tickets, eu, paris, residency, the-louvre

The website for the Louvre [mentions the following](https://www.louvre.fr/en/visit/hours-admission#visitors-eligible-for-free-admission) regarding ticket prices:

> Admission is free for the following visitors:
>
> –18 year olds
> Present official piece of ID.
>
> –26-year-old residents of the European Economic Area (EU, Norway,
> Iceland, and Liechtenstein)
> Present certificate of residence or valid
> piece of ID.

Is a holder of a temporary residence permit from an EU country (specifically, an employment permit from Germany) who is under the age of 26, eligible for free admission, or does one have to be a permanent resident of the EEA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It is hard to prove a negative but there is no requirement to be a permanent resident (which is *not* a well-defined term across the EEA and cannot be effectively checked).

In any case, in practice, a uniform format residence permit issued by EEA countries is accepted at Louvre and several other French museums without issue. National D-visas may require some explanation, but can be accepted.

Although issued with a uniform format resident permit like EEA countries, Swiss residents are not admissible free of charge since Switzerland is not part of the EU or the EEA (although in practice some staff members at smaller museums may not know this).

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that this worked in this situation.